# Google Protobuf without deserialization

Tags: python-3.x, casting, type-conversion, protocol-buffers, messaging

Normally, google `protobuf` or the `nanopb` implementation is intended to serialize/deserialize messages on the server/client side respectively.

However, I'm faced with a case where the serialization has been omitted on the server side, because somebody wanted to optimize it away (Probably relying on the byteorder being the same on client/server).

On the client side, I like to deserialize the messages, which fails for the said reason.
I receive a byte array from the server, but this byte array is just a cast of the original message to an array of bytes.

Now, I'm not able to set-up a `google.protobuf.message` from the byte array, because I cannot call `ParseFromString` on the cast.
What I need is something like the `int.from_bytes` method but for protobuf messages.

Say, I have a message `xx_pb2.MYMESSAGE` in the `protoc` generated source file `xx_pb2`.
I want to convert the byte array into this message (Pseudocode: `xx_pb2.MYMESSAGE.from_bytes(the_byte_array)`).

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the message flow. Why can't you reverse the function that's converting the Messages to bytes (on the client?)? I assume the Messages aren't being pickled. To ensure there's no confusion; it seems you're aware that `SerializeToString` is poorly named and converts Protobuf Messages to bytes (not strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

- In your client code, create a MYMESSAGE object.
- Fill in its attributes one at a time, extracting it from the byte array using things like int.from_bytes.
- Then, you can either
  a. Directly use that MYMESSAGE instance or
  b. You can serialize it to bytes and then, from those bytes, you can do the xx_pb2.MYMESSAGE.from_bytes(the_byte_array)